# OpenOffice xSentenceCursor stuck at end of paragraph

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I am using this routine to iterate over sentences in an OpenOffice document:

```
    while (moreParagraphsOO) {
        while (moreSentencesOO) {
            xSentenceCursor.gotoEndOfSentence(true);
            textSentence = xSentenceCursor.getString();
            xTextViewCursor.gotoRange(xSentenceCursor.getStart(), false);
            xTextViewCursor.gotoRange(xSentenceCursor.getEnd(), true);
            if (!textSentence.equals("")) {
                return textSentence;
            }
            moreSentencesOO = xSentenceCursor.gotoNextSentence(false);

        }

        moreParagraphsOO = xParagraphCursor.gotoNextParagraph(false);
        moreSentencesOO = xSentenceCursor.gotoStartOfSentence(false);
    }
```

It works fine unless it finds a paragraph which ends with ". ", this is, a period and one or several whitespaces after it. In that case it enters and infinite loop executing the

```
 while (moreSentencesOO)
    ...
    moreSentencesOO = xSentenceCursor.gotoNextSentence(false);
```

endlessly. I am not so proeficient with OpenOffice API, and I am quite stuck here. Any ideas?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I have come with a somewhat awkward patch consisting in checking the current position of the cursor, and if it does not advance between two iterations, jump to next paragraph:

```
    while (moreParagraphsOO) {
        while (moreSentencesOO) {

            /**********************************/
            int previousPosX = xTextViewCursor.getPosition().X;
            int previousPosY = xTextViewCursor.getPosition().Y;
            /*********************************/

            xSentenceCursor.gotoEndOfSentence(true);
            textSentence = xSentenceCursor.getString();
            xTextViewCursor.gotoRange(xSentenceCursor.getStart(), false);
            xTextViewCursor.gotoRange(xSentenceCursor.getEnd(), true);
            if (!textSentence.equals("")) {
                return textSentence;
            }            

            moreSentencesOO = xSentenceCursor.gotoNextSentence(false);

            /**********************************/
            if (previousPosX == xTextViewCursor.getPosition().X &&
                previousPosY == xTextViewCursor.getPosition().Y){
                    xParagraphCursor.gotoNextParagraph(false);
            }
            /**********************************/
        }
        moreParagraphsOO = xParagraphCursor.gotoNextParagraph(false);
        moreSentencesOO = xSentenceCursor.gotoStartOfSentence(false);
    }
```

It seems to work, but I am unsure about whether it could introduce future problems. I would rather prefer an "elegant" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [gotoNextSentence()](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/interfacecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1text_1_1XSentenceCursor.html#abe1b06dff54c376697c162c3dcbc0543), it should only return true if the cursor was moved, so this is a bug.  Consider [filing a report](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/QA/BugReport).

The problem seems to occur when [isEndOfSentence()](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XSentenceCursor.html#isEndOfSentence) but not [isStartOfSentence()](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XSentenceCursor.html#isStartOfSentence).  So test for that instead of `getPosition()`.

Here is Andrew Pitonyak's Basic macro that I modified to include this fix.

```vb
Sub CountSentences
    oCursor = ThisComponent.Text.createTextCursor()
    oCursor.gotoStart(False)
    Do
        nSentences = nSentences + 1
        If oCursor.isEndOfSentence() And Not oCursor.isStartOfSentence() Then
            oCursor.goRight(1, False)
        End If
    Loop While oCursor.gotoNextSentence(False)
    MsgBox nSentences & " sentences."
End Sub
```

Comment: abusing from your knowledge... I have a very similar question here, that nobody seems to be able to answer...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62637778/libreoffice-xparagraphcursor-stuck-when-blank-line